# Multiple public Firebase Database Instances in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an assignment. I've to use Database provided by a provider 'hacker-news'. Also i've to use Firebase Authentication. I've setup a new project in my own account. Retrieving data from Hacker-news database works with below line. I'm able to fetch publicly accessible data with firebase child() APIs is

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/");
```

But when i implemented Firebase Authentication and once user logs in it is giving error

> Provided authentication credentials are invalid. This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. Make sure your google-services.json file has the correct firebase_url and api_key

I've spent lot of time on internet and found a link to implement multiple databases in single project - 
[Working with multiple Firebase projects in an Android app by Google](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html)

This works only if you are the owner of those Databases. Is there anyway i can access Hacker-news Database using SDK not REST-API?

Answer (score 0):

```
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                        .setDatabaseUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.dbURL))
                        .setApiKey(getResources().getString(R.string.api))
                        .setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.appID))
                        .setProjectId(getResources().getString(R.string.projectId))
                        .setStorageBucket(getResources().getString(R.string.storageBucket)).build();
//set all variable above as your need

        boolean hasBeenInitialized=false;
                List<FirebaseApp> fireBaseApps = FirebaseApp.getApps(getApplicationContext());
                for(FirebaseApp app : fireBaseApps){
                    if(app.getName().equals("any_name")){
                        hasBeenInitialized=true;

                    }
                }

                if (!hasBeenInitialized) {
                    smaTeacher = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "any_name");

                }
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("any_name"));
```

Comment: I came across this solution but all i have is database URl, I don't have other parameters (projectId etc.,) of Hacker-News

Comment: What if you simply omit the other values and use just the database url in the FirebaseOptions builder?

Comment: Tried that too. It thrown me an error that projectId is required.